# angular 5: .scss changes are not being recognized in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using Angular 5.

Whenever I make changes to the .scss file are not working in the HTML file. The files being used are: **admin-login.component.ts**, **admin-login.component.css** and **admin-login.component.html** Definition of the file structure is below:

[image]

I make changes to the `admin-login.component.scss` file and nothing happens. Whenever I take the changes and add them to the `admin-login.component.html` file directly using `<style></style>` tags, things work.

Why is this the case?

TIA

**admin-login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-login',
  templateUrl: './admin-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-login.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  { document.getElementById('preloader').classList.add('hide');  }

}
```

**admin-login.component.css (defining style info here does not work)**

```
:host {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div.input {
    position: relative;
}

div.input label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 2px;
}

div.input input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    outline: 0;
}

div.input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


.main {
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**admin-login.component.html (adding style in HTML file works)**

```
<style>
  .main {
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="main">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
      <div class="input">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password">
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be an issue with your `angular-cli.json` file. 
Specifically:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "styles",
          "app/components",
          "app/containers"
        ]
    },
```